# working of threads simultaneously at process level?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, multitasking

In multi threading concept, we create different threads in a program. My question is, are threads part of a process and execute in parallel or take turns inside the process and execute?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say "inside the process", but generally speaking, the scheduling of threads is entirely up to the operating system, although most OS's provide some way of requesting thread and/or process priority.  In Java, you can set thread priority with the Thread.setPriotity method, but the Java runtime library doesn't expose process priority that I'm aware of (although you can generally use platform-specific libraries for this).

Whether or not threads actually run in parallel depends on whether they happen to be scheduled on separate processors at any point in time.  Otherwise, they won't run in parallel, but can preempt each other.  This means that the OS will run a thread for some time before pausing it and switching to another.

Many OS's also provide a way to assign a processor "affinity" to a thread, which can be used to increase the likelihood that it runs on a specific processor, but this also isn't exposed in the standard Java runtime library.

Comment: actually i wanted know that.....suppose if there are 2 processes inside a processor i.e., single core  and 1 of them is a process of our java program. Inside our program there are 2 threads. If processor gives time to our program process to execute then how will they run....1st option..both the threads will execute their code at once that is parallel (or) 2nd option..the threads will take turns decided by the thread scheduler and execute their code?

Comment: If you have only one processor core, your threads can't actually execute in parallel.  So, I think only the 2nd option is possible, if I understand your scenario correctly.